# What is the correct way to query MongoDB for _id using string by using Python?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am using pymongo driver.  Supposedly, one can use a string to query the _id field of a document, like this:

```
thing = db.things.find_one({'_id':'4ea113d6b684853c8e000001'})
```

But it doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It should be :

```
from pymongo.objectid import ObjectId   
thing = db.things.find_one({'_id': ObjectId('4ea113d6b684853c8e000001') })
```

EDIT:
The current import is:
`from bson.objectid import ObjectId`

Comment: for pymongo > 2.2 please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10919658/6613450

Answer (score 42):

PyMongo has changed its structure. `ObjectID` is no longer imported from `pymongo`, but from `bson`. It should now be:

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
thing = db.things.find_one({'_id': ObjectId('4ea113d6b684853c8e000001')})
```

As a reminder, per [pypi/pymongo](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymongo/), do not install the “bson” package. PyMongo comes with its own bson package; doing “pip install bson” installs a third-party package that is incompatible with PyMongo.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401499/mongokit-importerror-no-module-named-objectid-error

Answer (score 3):

To print it:

```
import pymongo
from bson.objectid import ObjectId    
print(db.things.find_one({'_id': ObjectId('4ea113d6b684853c8e000001')}))
```

if you don't want to print, store in other variable

Answer (score 0):

`thing = db.things.find_one({'_id':ObjectId('4ea113d6b684853c8e000001')})` should work

Comment: thanks lobster1234 your answer is also correct, but it was the import I was missing, cheers

Answer (score 0):

PyMongo documentation does not seem to be in sync with the current version. ObjectIds are now under bson.objectid namespace. If I remember right, they have been that way since version 2.3. 
Use from bson.objectid import ObjectId.