# ImportError: No module named objectid

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo, django-mongodb-engine

I have currently [django-mongodb-engine](http://django-mongodb.org/) 0.4.0 version installed on my Mac OS X 10.6.8 and weirdly encountered an interesting error while importing the 'compiler' module:

```
>> from django_mongodb_engine import compiler
```

and I got the following error:

```
ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions/management/commands/shell_plus.pyc in <module>()
----> 1 from django_mongodb_engine import compiler

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_mongodb_engine/compiler.pyc in <module>()
      15 from pymongo.errors import PyMongoError
      16 from pymongo import ASCENDING, DESCENDING
 ---> 17 from pymongo.objectid import ObjectId, InvalidId
      18 
      19 from djangotoolbox.db.basecompiler import NonrelQuery, NonrelCompiler, \

ImportError: No module named objectid
```

I installed the package via [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi) command and all the dependencies like [pymongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.2/), [djangotoolbox](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangotoolbox) have been installed along with it. The pip command I'd used is this:

```
>> sudo env ARCHFLAGS='-arch i386 -arch x86_64' pip install --upgrade  django-mongodb-engine
```

The current versions of the related packages are:

```
>> pip freeze | grep mongo
django-mongodb-engine==0.4.0
pymongo==2.2
```

I suspect the django_mongodb_engine package is broken because ObjectId is not imported inside pymongo anymore. Instead, it belongs to [bson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bson/0.3.2) module.

What are your suggestions to fix this problem? Should I clone the django-mongodb-engine project and fix on github?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I've ran into something similar, for me the problem was this line:

```
from pymongo.objectid import ObjectId
```

The call seems to work in versions of PyMongo < 2.2

In pymongo 2.2 the call to import objectid is:

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
```

Comment: To clarify, `ImportError: No module named bson.objectid` will result if you try `from bson.objectid import ObjectId` without `pymongo` installed in your environment. If you run pip/conda install pymongo or get it some other way, `from bson.objectid import ObjectId` should then work.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like they're already aware (see [this pull request](https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine/pull/130)), but no one's created a pull request against the develop branch yet. You could try fixing that and submit a new pull request.

Comment: I got the patch for this commit. Looks like, it was patched 12 days ago, not in 0.4.0 version. https://github.com/mgmtech/mongodb-engine/commit/d3cba0d013350d5b085bed9ea440a04b232f8575

Answer (score 2):

I tried to install bson with pip directly. Uninstall, and install pymongo instead and the error didnt reappear.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Python3 (in 2017) and found that the following works:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson import ObjectId
```

Answer (score 0):

for me installing pymongo solved my issue:

```
pip3 install pymongo
```

source: https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/how-to-install-pymongo-and-connect-to-mongodb-in-python-363