# how to update entire object without changing the id in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I am trying to update all properties of the record/object which is stored in MongoDB, now I am trying to do like this.

1. Deleted the object, but keeping the ID of the object being deleted.
2. Create a new object with the same ID which I have deleted.

Is it correct ? or What is they to do above objective using  `pymongo` ?

```
mongo_object = {
 _id : 123,
 prop_key_1: some_value,
 // ... many present
 prop_key_n: some_value,
}

def delete(record):
    doc = get_db().reviews.delete_many({"id" : record["_id"]})
    print(doc.deleted_count)

# all key values are changed, mongo_object is changed except the id.


delete(mongo_object)
db.collection_name.insert_one(mongo_object)
```

But above code is not deleting the object, the `doc.deleted_count` is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
 from bson.objectid import ObjectId 
 def replace_one(record):
            result = client.test_db.test_collection.replace_one({"_id":ObjectId(record["_id"])}, record,upsert=True)
            print(result.matched_count)
```

[What is the correct way to query MongoDB for _id using string by using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846001/what-is-the-correct-way-to-query-mongodb-for-id-using-string-by-using-python)

Pymongo doc - http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.replace_one

Answer (score 2):

```
db.collection_name.update_one({"_id" : record["_id"]}, new_data}
```

just use update without $set , the document will get replaced completely without changing the _id

Comment: In pymongo 4.1.1 this produces "ValueError: update only works with $ operators".  However, substituting "replace_one" for "update_one" in this answer works great.