Difficulty to query on MongoDB based on ObjectId
I'm building a ChatBot Rag using LangChain, Mistral and HuggingFace.
I need to send to my script the user id to check on my Mongo database the data from a specific user. The problem is this collection use a ObjectId and I don't know how to pass the userId to query right the data.
Here is the reflection mongo model:
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const reflectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
  question: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'DailyQuestion', required: false },
  content: { type: String, required: true },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Reflection', reflectionSchema);

When my user signin I have this return from my api
{
    "token": "...",
    "userId": "65d8937f6408bf2c0ca8d264"
}

When I need fetch my reflections from a specific user
// GET all reflections for a user
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const reflections = await Reflection.find({ user: req.user._id })
                                         .populate('question');
    res.json(reflections);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error.toString());
  }
});

I send in my header req the auth token from a specific user and I fetch the reflections from this is specific user.
This is working fine.
The problem is when I try to send this userId to my ChatBot Python Script
Here is the code:
from langchain_community.document_loaders import TextLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Pinecone
from langchain_community.llms import HuggingFaceEndpoint
import pinecone
from pymongo import MongoClient
from certifi import where  # Import certifi library
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

class ChatBot():
    def __init__(self):
        load_dotenv()

        # Check database connection
        try:
            self.client = MongoClient(
                "my mongo-uri here",
                tls=True,  # Enable TLS encryption
                tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=False,  # Don't allow invalid certificates
                tlsCAFile=where()  # Use certifi library for CA bundle
            )
            self.client.server_info()  # Attempt a connection to verify
            print("Connected to MongoDB successfully.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error connecting to MongoDB: {e}")
            exit(1)

        # Get database name from environment variable (optional)
        db_name = os.getenv('DB_NAME', 'test')  # Default to 'test'
        print(f"Using database: {db_name}")
        self.db = self.client[db_name]

        # Text processing (assuming user data is a string)
        def load_documents(user_data):
            documents = [user_data]
            text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=4)
            docs = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
            return docs

        self.embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings()

        pinecone.init(
            api_key=os.getenv('PINECONE_API_KEY'),
            environment='gcp-starter'
        )

        self.index_name = "langchain-demo"

        if self.index_name not in pinecone.list_indexes():
            pinecone.create_index(name=self.index_name, metric="cosine", dimension=768)
            docsearch = Pinecone.from_documents(load_documents(""), self.embeddings, index_name=self.index_name)  # Create empty index
        else:
            docsearch = Pinecone.from_existing_index(self.index_name, self.embeddings)

        self.repo_id = "mistralai/Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1"
        self.llm = HuggingFaceEndpoint(
            repo_id=self.repo_id, temperature=0.8, top_p=0.8, top_k=50, huggingfacehub_api_token=os.getenv('HUGGINGFACE_API_KEY')
        )

        from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate

        self.template = """
        You are a seer. These Human will ask you a questions about their life. Use following piece of context to answer the question. 
        If you don't know the answer, just say you don't know. 
        You answer with short and concise answer, no longer than2 sentences.

        Context: {context}
        Question: {question}
        Answer: 

        """

        self.prompt = PromptTemplate(template=self.template, input_variables=["context", "question"])

        from langchain.schema.runnable import RunnablePassthrough
        from langchain.schema.output_parser import StrOutputParser

        self.rag_chain = (
            {"context": docsearch.as_retriever(), "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
            | self.prompt
            | self.llm
            | StrOutputParser()
        )

    # Define get_user_data method outside __init__
    def get_user_data(self, user_id):
        collection = self.db["reflections"]  # Replace with your actual collection name (check in MongoDB)
        cursor = collection.find({"user": user_id})  # Filter by user_id
        user_data = [doc["data"] for doc in cursor]  # Extract data field from documents
        print("Documents found:", list(cursor))  # Print documents found for debugging
        return user_data[0] if user_data else None  # Return first document or None

bot = ChatBot()
user_id = input("Enter your user ID: ")  # Get user ID
user_data = bot.get_user_data(user_id)  # Retrieve user data

print(f"Retrieved user data: {user_data}")

When I answer in the terminal the same userId like this 65d8937f6408bf2c0ca8d264, this not found anything.
I try query this on MongoDB Atlas and have the same problem.
When I retrieve my reflections from my API in insomnia I have this
{
 "_id": "65d897edc82af4dbcbb3215c",
 "user": "65d8937f6408bf2c0ca8d264",
 "content": "teste",
 "createdAt": "2024-02-23T13:04:45.261Z",
 "__v": 0
},

But When I check on MongoDB I have this:
_id: 65cbd5b61af271221d1a1252
user: 65c6759919c1c17c97000ae5
content: "obrigado pelo dia"
createdAt: 2024-02-13T20:48:54.392+00:00
__v: 0

I don't know how to pass in my terminal to test this script my userId.
I tried send in the terminal like this: '65d8937f6408bf2c0ca8d264' and this "ObjectId('65d8937f6408bf2c0ca8d264'), but didn't works.
Maybe someone more senior can help me. I appreciates any explanation.

you have to pass an ObjectId instance for the id, not a string - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17324354/202168
